# `No module named...` while deploying an AWS Lambda using Serverless Framework, poetry, python3.10 and fastapi

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, python-poetry

### EDIT

Il looks like theproblem comes from the Serverless plugin, `serverless-python-requirements`.

When packaging with `$ sls package`, when having `python = "^3.9"` the dependencies are in the zip, but having `python = "^3.10"` they are not. Everything else is the same.

**end of edit**

---

I want to deploy an AWS Lambda using *Serverless Framework*, *poetry*, *python3.10* and *fastapi*.

I did the same thing using *python3.9* and it worked. It must be something with my local config, can you help, please?

The answer I get when calling the endpoint `https://***********.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/development/api/health-check/` is `{"message": "Internal server error"}`.

The lambda's log says:

```bash
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'fastapi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins="*", allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])

@app.get("/api/health-check/")
def health_check():
    return {"message": "OK"}

handle = Mangum(app)
```

Here is what I do:

```bash
$ poetry init
.....
Compatible Python versions [^3.9]:  3.10

Would you like to define your main dependencies interactively? (yes/no) [yes] no
Would you like to define your development dependencies interactively? (yes/no) [yes] no
Generated file
.....
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.10"
```

```bash
$ poetry add --dev pytest pytest-cov black isort flake8 bandit
The currently activated Python version 3.9.9 is not supported by the project (3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.

Poetry was unable to find a compatible version. If you have one, you can explicitly use it via the "env use" command.
```

On my machine I have 3 versions of python:
[image]

```bash
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.9

$ python3.10 --version
Python 3.10.11
```

Editing the python version in `pyproject.toml` seams to unlock the situation:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.10"
```

```bash
$ poetry add --dev pytest pytest-cov black isort flake8 bandit
The currently activated Python version 3.9.9 is not supported by the project (~3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.
Using python3.10 (3.10.11)
Creating virtualenv test-sls-deploy-md9kc90P-py3.10 in /Users/costin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs
.....

$ poetry add fastapi uvicorn httpx
The currently activated Python version 3.9.9 is not supported by the project (~3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.
Using python3.10 (3.10.11)
Using version ^0.95.1 for fastapi
.....
```

Then I deploy with

```bash
$ sls deploy --stage development --verbose
```

I get a warning that `python3.10` is not in the list of expected runtime environments, but it deploys correctly.

Here is the `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
service: test-sls-deploy-api

frameworkVersion: '3'
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.10
  region: 'eu-west-3'
  stage: 'development'
  logRetentionInDays: 30

functions:
  TEST-DEPLOY:
    handler: main.handle
    memorySize: 512
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: any
          cors:
            origin: ${env:ALLOWED_ORIGINS}
            maxAge: 60

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    usePoetry: true
    noDeploy:
      - boto3  # already on Lambda
      - botocore  # already on Lambda

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

I was expecting the plugin `serverless-pytohn-requirements` to handle the deployment of `fastapi` as it does with `python3.9`, but with `python3.10` things do not happen as expected.

Do you see what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the root cause of the problem, but doing that, solved the problem:

- Uninstall `python3.9` and made `python3.10` answer to `python3`.
- In `pyproject.toml` using `python = "^3.10"` instead of `python = "~3.10"`
- I do not know if that has an impact, but I've also created the `.venv` in project folder with

```ini
## poetry.toml
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

In order to debug I used `$ sls package` and compare the `.zip` until the dependencies were there.

⚠️ There is still a warning from `sls` when deploying because it doesn't expect `python3.10`, but since AWS CloudFormation is ok with that everything is ok and the lambdas have the `python3.10` runtime.